# C-How to read words from a text file into an array of strings

Tags: c, arrays

I need to write a program that generates a table mapping words onto the number of times the word appears in a text file. So far my code looks like this

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
struct entry
{
  char* word;
  unsigned int n;
  struct entry *left;
  struct entry *right;
};

struct entry* 
insert(struct entry *table, char *str)
{
  if(table==NULL){
    table = (struct entry*)malloc(sizeof(struct entry));
    table->word = str;
    table->n = 1;
    table->left = NULL;
    table->right = NULL;
  }else if(strcmp(table->word,str)==0){
    table->n=(table->n)+1;
  }else if(strcmp(table->word,str)==1){
    table->left=insert(table->left,str);
  }else{
    table->right = insert(table->right,str);
  }
  return table;
}

void
print_table(struct entry *table)
{
  if(!(table==NULL)){
    print_table(table->left);
    fprintf(stdout,"%s\t %d\n",table->word,table->n);
    print_table(table->right);
  }
}

int
main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{

  struct entry* table = NULL;
  char *str = "foo";
  table =  insert(table,str);
  str = "foo";
  table = insert(table,str); 
  print_table(table);

  return 0;

}
```

which gives an out put of

```
foo 2
```

what I need to do is do this exact thing with an input file. My idea is to take every word of the text file which will look like

```
This is an example of 
what the text file
will look like.
```

I have no idea what the exact number of lines or words per line are. As I was saying, my idea was to take every word from the text file and put it into an array of strings, then run my insert function through every element in the array, I just have no idea how I should go about taking each word and putting it in the array. Any suggestions are welcome and appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Portability bug

Note that this use of `strcmp()` is wrong:

```
}else if(strcmp(table->word,str)==1){
```

The definition of `strcmp()` is that it returns a value less than zero, equal to zero, or greater than zero.  No mention of `1`.

Always, but always, compare with 0:

- `if (strcmp(word, str) == 0)` — `word` equal to `str`
- `if (strcmp(word, str) != 0)` — `word` not equal to `str`
- `if (strcmp(word, str) <= 0)` — `word` less than or equal to `str`
- `if (strcmp(word, str) >= 0)` — `word` greater than or equal to `str`
- `if (strcmp(word, str) <  0)` — `word` less than `str`
- `if (strcmp(word, str) >  0)` — `word` greater than `str`

In many implementations, the return value from `strcmp()` is the numeric difference between the characters that differ, and can be much larger or smaller than 1.

#### Reading words

If you're reasonably sure your input won't be wholly insane, you can use a variant on this loop to read the data:

```
char buffer[4096];
while (fscanf(fp, "%4095s", buffer) == 1)
{
    char *word = strdup(buffer);
    table = insert(table, word);
}
```

This reads words up to 4 KiB long and stores each one in your table using your function.  If a word is exactly 4 KiB long or longer than that, it will be split into pieces.  It probably won't be a problem.  Note that the `scanf()` family treats blanks, tabs and newlines as the separators between words.  Writing `"a-z"` in a file gets treated as one word, double quotes, dash and all.

Comment: We are to assume that there is no punctuation and the words are delimited by white space characters.

Comment: In which case, the code shown will work very comfortably for you.  You could probably reduce the 4 KiB to 256 or some smaller number if you really want to, but 4 KiB isn't a problem on most machines these days.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store every word of the following paragraph

```
This is an example of 
what the text file
will look like.
```

The following will work:

```
while(true){
    while(inFile >> yourword){
    //store yourword here
    }
    getline(inFile, yourword); //discards the newline
    if(/*some_conditional_to_break*/)
    break;
}
```

Comment: Turbo C lol. Seriously, C have getline C++ also have getline. Also Have while loop. boolen of true, if conditions and break. So why do you ask?

Comment: Ive never seen ">>" or "true" in C

Comment: @Aizen: the C (POSIX) getline is quite different from the C++ getline.

Comment: This is not C; it is C++.  You should ignore the misinformation in this answer.  It is valid if the question is about C++; this question is not about C++ so it is invalid.

Comment: Good tagging into C. It was just in Array a while ago.

Comment: It got the [tag:c] tag very quickly then; it was tagged with [tag:c] when I first looked at it.

Comment: I did not C the C tag.

Comment: @etorr96 you've never shifted a bit to the right ? :)